# No route matches [POST] "/" when posting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to set up a form on my index page that will pass a param  `myform`, to the same index page via a GET request. I thought this would be relatively simple. but I'm getting an error.

I generated a controller, `RecipesController`, with a method called `index`:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = params[:myform] 
    return @search
  end
end
```

In this method I'm trying to get back what the user types into a textbox when a button is pressed and the GET request is fired.

Here is my view:

```
<h1>Recipe Finder</h1>

<%= form_tag(controller:"recipes",method:"get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:myform, "Search") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:myform) %>
<%= submit_tag("search")  %>
<% end %>
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'recipes#index'
```

This shows up fine when I visit `localhost:3000`, but when I press the button I'm expecting the controller `index` method to just return whatever text i typed into the textbox. Unfortunately, I only get:

```
No route matches [POST] "/"
```

I know setting the root to `recipes#index` is causing the failure as my `@search` variable is not set when the page is opened initially.

I'm wondering if I should have a separate route and method for the GET request and should I just open the main page with the call to `localhost:3000` without running any code in the controller? Is this possible?

Comment: Try adding `resources :recipes` to `routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) accepts a `Hash` as both its first and second argument. If you don't use brackets, it's going to interpret all of it as part of the first argument, and your `method: "get"` is not applied properly.

Because of this, it defaults to doing a POST request, for which there is no route.

Try this. Because the first argument is no longer a `Hash`, it should work properly:

```
<%= form_tag("/", method: "get") do %>
```

Alternatively, using your code, you can try this:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: "recipes" }, { method: "get" }) do %>
```